# Excel: Sum columns and rows if criteria is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I have a sheet with product names in column I and then dates from there on. For each date there are numbers of how many pieces of a certain product have to be made. I'm trying to sum all those numbers based on a product type, i.e.:

```
 I       K       L      M     ...

        30.8.   31.8.   1.9.   ...
MAD23     2       0      45    ...
MMR32     5       7      33    ...
MAD17    17      56       0    ...

MAD:    120  (2+0+45+17+56+0)
MMR:     45  (5+7+33)
```

What I'm doing now is sum the row first:

=SUM(K6:GN6)

```
MAD23 = 47
MMR32 = 45
MAD32 = 73
```

And then sum those numbers in column J based on part of the product name in column I:

=SUMIF(Sheet1!I6:I775;"MAD*";Sheet1!J6:J775)

```
MAD = 120
MMR = 45
```

Is it possible to do this with just **one** formula per criteria?

Comment: Can you please clarify the coulmn in you example?

Comment: I added column names in the post. Column J contains formula =SUM(K6:GN6).

Comment: Then just change the j6:j775 in your formula to k6:gn775. Tell me if it works.

Comment: You could run a SUM with the help of the MATCH ( https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a ) or VLOOKUP ( https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)  commands

Comment: @Balinti I've tried that but it doesn't work. The formula gives 0.

Comment: Don nok why th * is not working. So I wrote another answer. check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trying it on those three rows, I get

```
=SUM($K$6:$M$8*(LEFT($I$6:$I$8,LEN(I10)-1)=LEFT(I10,LEN(I10)-1)))
```

which is an array formula and must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

That's assuming that I10 is going to contain some characters followed by  a colon and you want to match those with the first characters of I6:I8.

[image]

Comment: Uh, I forgot one more thing. Is it possible to modify the formula and add another condition that would check row 5, where the dates are, to count the numbers only if the dates are <=today(). I tried this, but I get the value 0. =SUM(Sheet1!$J$6:$GM$775*(LEFT(Sheet1!$I$6:$I$775;LEN(A2)-1)=LEFT(A2;LEN(A2)-1))*(Sheet1!J5:GM5<=TODAY()))

Comment: Your formula looks OK to me, I'm puzzled why it isn't working. The formatting of the dates looks a bit odd on your example, maybe check that they are stored as dates and not text and that they are 2015? If you change the format to general temporarily, they should show up as a number e.g. 42246.

Comment: The dates had an apostrophe ('), that's why it didn't work. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(IF(MID(Sheet1!I6:I775,1,3)="MAD",Sheet1!k6:gn775,""))
```

With ctrl +shift+enter